# Contrast adjustment of two images

Tags: image-processing, itk, medical, simpleitk

I have two images with different contrast scale. How can I get the second image to have the same contrast scale? Is there any technique to do that? Does the histogram matching technique work for this purpose?

Comment: you can use contrast adjustment [law](https://i.imgur.com/3cC1FYe.jpg)

Comment: Histogram matching should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleITK [*HistogramMatchingImageFilter*](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1HistogramMatchingImageFilter.html#details):

```py
import SimpleITK as sitk

# read images
im_ref = sitk.ReadImage("/path/to/reference/image")
im_orig = sitk.ReadImage("/path/to/image/to/be/modified")

# apply histogram matching
histogram_match = sitk.HistogramMatchingImageFilter()
histogram_match.SetThresholdAtMeanIntensity(True)  # useful if a lot of background pixels
im_matched = histogram_match.Execute(im_orig, im_ref)

# write output
sitk.WriteImage(im_matched, "/path/for/output/image")
```